# awk compare two files gives unexpected output when swapping the position of argument files

Tags: awk

Below are my two files' content:

**cat f1**

```
9  
5  
3
```

**cat f2**

```
1  
2  
3
```

This is my code, which works perfectly and gives output as per my understanding:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} FNR in a' f1 f2
3
```

But, when I swap the position of these 2 argument files, the output is different than what I expected.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} FNR in a' f2 f1  
9  
5  
3
```

I expected the output as 3 again as like previous, because f2 and f1 both has exactly 3 lines and the key 3 is however stored in the hash map. Please explain how the 2nd code works.

Comment: learn to debug your code by adding statmements like `print "#dbg: FNR="FNR "\t$0=" $0`. etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the second example is, of course, correct.

Since `f2` contains the values 1, 2, 3, the array `a` ends up with elements `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`.  When it is processing `f1`, line 1 has `FNR == 1`, and `1` is an index in `a`, so line 1 (containing `9`) is printed; similarly for lines 2 and 3, hence the output you see.